# kubectl delete Waited for 1.198125751s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness

Tags: kubernetes, throttling

when I try to delete some resources,
method A:  kubectl delete a,b,c,d
reports:

```
dropresource-advance-177-delete-hdpscluster-resource-2555227192: I0705 13:24:18.892538      25 request.go:601] Waited for 1.198125751s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://172.20.0.1:443/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1?timeout=32s
```

mothod B:

```
kubectl delete a
kubectl delete b
kubectl delete c
kubectl delete d
kubectl delete e
```

I delete them seperately, I found it becomes very quick.

is there anyone who knows the mechanism in k8s, and explain why?

Comment: some more information, there are crd resources in the a, b, c, d, e